# (Fluent) linq group by strong type

Tags: c#, linq

I don't get this, maybe somebody will light me up.
This works:

```
var grouped = getRuntimeParams(sheet, pcode)
  .GroupBy(x => new { 
     dbTable = x.dbTable, 
     dbIndexField = x.dbIndexField, 
     dbIndex = x.dbIndex });
```

Which means I get the rows grouped as they should be.
This does not, meaning that the result is "grouped" row by row:

```
var grouped = getRuntimeParams(sheet, pcode)
  .GroupBy(x => new ParamGroup { 
     dbTable = x.dbTable, 
     dbIndexField = x.dbIndexField, 
     dbIndex = x.dbIndex });
```

But I need to pass the resulting group to a method, thus I need it strongly typed. Of course the ParamGroup class is public, with public properties as can be seen here.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Do `ParamGroup` class have `Equals` as well as `GetHashCode` methods *overriden*?

Comment: What means your result is not grouped row by row?

Comment: It means that there is a single row in each group.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that could be it!

Comment: Btw, if these 3 properties should be used as group-key, all `ParamGroup` instances will have the same. Does `getRuntimeParams` return multiple `ParamGroup`s? Do you want the original instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *override* `ParamGroup` class `Equals` as well as `GetHashCode` methods, something like this:

```
public class ParamGroup {

  ... 

  public override bool Equals(Object o) {
    ParamGroup other = o as ParamGroup;

    if (null == other)
      return false;

    return dbTable == other.dbTable &&
           dbIndexField == other.dbIndexField &&
           dbIndex == other.dbIndex;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return (dbIndexField == null ? 0 : dbIndexField.GetHashCode()) ^
            dbIndex ^
           (dbTable == null ? 0 : dbTable.GetHashCode());
  }
}
```

The cause of the misbehaviour is that when *not overriden* `ParamGroup` uses *default* `Equals` implementation (from `Object`) which compare *references*, not instances' fields/properties and so you have all instances being *different* (non-equal).

Anonymous types (in your first sample) *override* these methods:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: He could also select the original `ParamGroup` instances after the `GroupBy` of the anonymous type if `getRuntimeParams` returned them: `var grouped = getRuntimeParams(sheet, pcode).GroupBy(x => new {  x.dbTable, x.dbIndexField, x.dbIndex }).Select(g => g.ToList());`

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the first query works and the second one puts each row in a group by itself points to only one thing: `ParamGroup` does not have a proper implementation of `Equals` and `HashCode`.

If this is your class, implementing these method will fix the problem. Otherwise, you need to use an overload that takes an [equality comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).